# How to Install and use FANN with Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, installation, fann

i want to use FANN (fast artificial neural network) with Xcode 
i googled for a way how to get the FANN and install it in Xcode but i did not find a result
please guys does anyone know from where can i download FANN library and use it with Xcode 
thanks

Comment: http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/help/installing-fann/

This is a start...

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://leenissen.dk. Here you will find the source code you can download from sourceforge.com and install instructions for Cmake on the command line. Just follow the instructions and you will see several static libraries were included. Now all you will have to do is add the library you want to use and the include (.h) files to your Xcode project. From here the example code from the FANN website should work.
Note that when you reference the FANN .h files to your projects files you must use include and not import. I ran into this problem myself.

There was a issue with exporting a code signed application using Xcode. I was able to find a solution after playing around with code signing.
I decided to try manually code signing my app with instructions from http://www.digicert.com/code-signing/mac-os-codesign-tool.htm. This did not work. However the code signing tool pointed me to a problem with libfann.2.2.0.dylib. So I checked if libfann.2.2.0.dylib was code signed and it was not. When I saw this I thought I would try code signing libfann.2.2.0.dylib with my developer ID and re-importing it into my project. This strategy worked and I was able to export a developer ID signed version of my application.